# Lazarus cross compile from linux to win

Tags: cross-compiling, lazarus

I made a lazarus project on linux (ubuntu) and I need an .exe file for windows. Is there a way how can I do that?

Comment: Did you look in the documentation? http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling and http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling_for_Win32_under_Linux

Comment: In decreasing order of easiness, install Lazarus for Windows (standalone install, install in VM, or maybe even in Wine) or crosscompile. Crosscompiling is not very hard, but the chance that your distro prepackages it readily made is not high.

Answer (score 1):

Another way if, as suggested, you read the documentation and can't get it to work is to simply install the lazarus windows version on a windows machine and compile your code on that windows machine to an .exe

Comment: That's not cross compiling